# IntegrityError: null value in column "city_id " violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, models

I two model:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.OneToOneField(Country)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name 


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    city = models.OneToOneField(City)
```

when I syncdb and create admin user :

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "city_id" violates not-null constraint
```

How I can Fix this error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
city = models.OneToOneField(City)
```

Are you sure you want only one user per city? I think you need

```
city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank=True)
```

`null, blank` because the `sycndb` will create a profile and will fail if no `city` is passed.

Alternatively, you can pass `default=default_city_id` to the `city` `ForeignKey`