# Django - null value in column violates not-null constraint in Django Admin

Tags: python, sql, mysql, django, django-admin

I'm facing an Integrity Error in Django admin while trying to add data to the database.

The traceback is as follows:

```
  Environment:


  Request Method: POST
  Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/site/admin/SilverInningsHelpline/classified/add/

  Django Version: 1.6.4
  Python Version: 2.7.3
  Installed Applications:
  ('django_admin_bootstrapped.bootstrap3',
   'django_admin_bootstrapped',
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'SilverInningsHelpline',
   'south')
  Installed Middleware:
  ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


  Traceback:
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
    114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
    432.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
    99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
    52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
    198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
    29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
    99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
    25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
    371.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
    1131.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, False)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
    860.         obj.save()
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
    545.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
    573.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
    654.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
    687.                                using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
    232.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
    1511.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
    903.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
    69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
    53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
    99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/siddharth/SilverInnings/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
    53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

  Exception Type: IntegrityError at /site/admin/SilverInningsHelpline/classified/add/
  Exception Value: null value in column "category_id" violates not-null constraint
```

My models are as follows:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.type

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Classified(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20, default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='dynamic/img/')
    NO = 'NO'
    YES = 'YES'
    APPROVAL = ((NO, 'no'), (YES, 'yes'))
    active = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3)
    verified = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The problems arise when I try to make an entry to the Classified table from Admin.

Tried solution from here:

[IntegrityError: null value in column "city_id " violates not-null constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603657/integrityerror-null-value-in-column-city-id-violates-not-null-constraint) as it was the closest to my problem. My tables looked like this after trying the solution on that link:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, default='All', null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.type

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Categories, null=True, blank=True, default='All')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Classified(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20, default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='dynamic/img/')
    NO = 'NO'
    YES = 'YES'
    APPROVAL = ((NO, 'no'), (YES, 'yes'))
    active = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3)
    verified = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

But this did not solve my problem and now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at your models you shouldn't have field `category_id` in any of your tables. Perhaps you changed your models but did not alter tables in the database. Now when you create an entry, Django does not fill fields it doesn't know about of and this creates an error. You should remove unneeded fields from your tables. Or if it is possible you can drop the whole database and run `manage.py syncdb` from scratch.

Comment: Would it better if I remove the category primary key field 'id'? Or is it specifically looking for a field called 'category_id'? Also, dropping this database would mean, I'd have to reflect that on Heroku where it's currently deployed and I don't wish to lose any of the live data.

Comment: I understand. Looks like you have `category_id` field in your table, but Django does not know about it. So `INSERT` statement it issues leaves this field blank, but you have NOT NULL constraint. If you have direct access to your database, you should check which table has this column and decide if you need it. If it is not specified in Django then perhaps you are not going to use it.

Comment: Hmm, I dropped the database and made a new one. `manage.py syncdb` works well and schemamigration worked too. Hopefully, on push I wont lose data.

Comment: `manage.py syncdb` command is deprecated in django 1.7. Use the `python manage.py migrate` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `null=True` in all your Fields check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#postgresql

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below with [models.ForeignKey()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "categories_id"
> of relation "my_app_product" violates not-null constraint

Because I didn't set [null=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#null) when setting [blank=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#blank) to `models.ForeignKey()`, then tried to add the blank data `---------` on **Add** page in Django Admin as shown below. *For `models.ForeignKey()` and [models.OneToOneField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) in Django, we need to set `null=True` when setting `blank=True`:

```py
# "my_app/models.py"

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, 
        blank=True, # Here 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

[image]

So, I set `null=True` with `blank=True` to `models.ForeignKey()` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
# "my_app/models.py"

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, 
        blank=True,
        null=True, # Here
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```